# ASP.NET MVC lookup for form field

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

We've got an ASP.NET MVC-based business form with multiple text boxes to fill out (e.g. a use-case would be "Register person" -> form contains: Name, ..., Father, Mother, ...)

The data entry clerk should not be forced to input father/mother himself, he should be able to search for the person in the system. It is not enough to have some kind of autocomplete field or popup, he should be able to make use of the full-fledged search page we already implemented (Person controller has SearchIndex & SearchPerson action, user has all kind of search options).

The final UI should look like this: Register person form has a button "Select father" which switches the UI to the search page, user searches the person and has the ability to click "Select" on a row in the result table which returns the UI back to the register person form, father-data is now filled into the read-only fields (hidden ID, name & birth date are visible but not editable).

**Our problem/question:** What is the recommended way to

a) save already entered data in the original form when opening the search form? Is it really necessary to open the search form in a jquery dialog with an IFRAME inside to stay on the same page and not lose the entered data?

b) how to return the selected ID back to the original form and pre-fill the readonly text boxes?

I hope you know what we're trying to achieve, otherwise please comment and I will clarify the question.

Comment: Personally I think nesting the search page on the form with a jQuery dialog or iframe is more pleasing and provides a better user experience than navigating away to the search page and coming back with the selected record.  I think the implementation is easier as well.  This is a good use case for a partial view.

Comment: Okay, however, is it necessary to use an IFRAME? Are there any drawbacks using an IFRAME here? Some people recommend to never use IFRAMEs...

Comment: I haven't used an iframe personally so cannot comment to their advantages but I have used the jQuery UI dialog plugin and it is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement something new and use the Jquery UI Dialog to do the search and and selection. You may/should refactor the existing search system to support different UIs for exactly this purpose or just code a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I see two alternatives:

- You can leverage client side technology. You can either open a modal or populate a div with your search person action result. Once the user finds the father, you can move that data to the appropriated container (read-only text field) and close the search container.
- You can do all server side. You can always use session to store the data the user typed already, take the user to the search view, and once the user picks the father, you can populate the information stored in session with the father data. The initial form can look on that session variable/object to populate the input fields if they are available.

**Notes**:

- You can always combine client/server side technologies as needed.
- You can use the session, as suggested, but any other storage mechanism for transient data would do the job (key value store: Redis? document db, etc).

Comment: If possible, we do not want to use sessions due to performance/scalability issues. If we make use of the modal dialog options and the user presses the search button, wouldn't the whole page be reloaded instead of only the modal dialog?

Comment: Not if you use ajax, there is support for ajax calls built in ASP.MVC (Ajax.BeginForm) or you can do this in plain jquery.

Comment: It would not have to be reloaded if you have the markup already in the page, just hidden.  Alternatively you could pull in the markup for the search with ajax.

Comment: Personally I don't use session neither, I would rather use Redis to store this type of data. Depending on the size and nature of your application it might not be a problem using the session.

Comment: There are 2 ways to make your search view available on the form. You can load the view and keep it hidden until the user clicks on "Find Father" and you make it visible. Or you can load the view with ajax by using .load(url). IF the user ALWAYS has to pick a father, the first method is ok, if not, the second saves you from loading all that html for cases where you might not need it.

Comment: @RacielR.: If we use Ajax to load the form on demand into a JQuery UI dialog - what happens if we press the search button within that form? Is only the dialog posted and the resulting table is shown on the jquery dialog or is the whole page posted?

Comment: There are several concepts mixing up here. Let's assume you make the search form available on the page by calling the corresponding action through .load() from the client side. When the user clicks on the search button, you need to invoke the search action using ajax too, either by using Jquery or by using the Ajax.BeginForm within your search form. Either way your action will be called asynchronously in the background and you then can make the search results available in the page w/o leaving it. How you draw those results in the page is another subject, but I would use a template engine.

Comment: Drawing those results can use the same ASP.Net MVC template engine and just return a partial view.  (I'm not a fan of two template engines running for a website at the same time, typically that means editing two views that represent the same thing).